# Liferay advanced navigation

Tags: templates, navigation, themes, liferay, velocity

I'm trying to make a somewhat unorthodox navigation in Liferay by making my own velocity template. However, it seems that my markup isn't working. Here's what I'm trying to do:

I want a main choice between 4 different options.
For each option there is a sub menu in two levels.
So far, it should be simple enough.
However, I want the main choice menu to be separate from the sub menu (mainly because the different sections are more or less different sites).

This is what I'm going for:

```
<nav id="portal-choice">
    <ul>
        <li class="selected">Option 1</li>
        <li>Option 2</li>
        <li>Option 3</li>
        <li>Option 4</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<nav id="main-nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="parent-menu">Child of selected
            <ul class="child-menu">
                <li>Grandchild of selected</li>
                <li>Grandchild of selected</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="parent-menu">Child of selected
            <ul class="child-menu">
                <li>Grandchild of selected</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Child of selected</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is what I tried:

```
<nav id="portal-choice">
    <ul>
        #foreach ($nav_item in $nav_items)
            #set ($navHasChildren = $nav_item.hasChildren())
            #set ($nav_item_class = "")

            #if ($nav_item.isSelected())
                <li class="selected">
            #else
                <li>
            #end
                    <a href="$nav_item.getURL()" $nav_item.getTarget()>$nav_item.icon() $nav_item.getName()</a>
                </li>
            #if ($nav_item.isSelected())
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <nav class="$nav_css_class" id="main-nav" title='#language("navigation")'>
                    <ul>
                        #if ($navHasChildren)
                            #foreach ($nav_child in $nav_item.getChildren())
                                #set ($hasGrandChildren = $nav_child.hasChildren())
                                #set ($nav_child_class = "")

                                #if ($nav_child.isSelected() || $nav_child.isChildSelected())
                                    #set ($nav_child_class = "selected")
                                #end
                                #if ($hasGrandChildren)
                                    #set ($nav_child_class = ${nav_child_class} + " parent-menu")
                                #end

                                <li class="$nav_child_class">
                                    <a href="$nav_child.getURL()" class="nav-link" $nav_child.getTarget()><span class="navigation-item">$nav_child.icon() $nav_child.getName()</span></a>
                                    #if ($hasGrandChildren)
                                        <a href="#" class="toggle-menu"></a>
                                    #end

                                    #if ($hasGrandChildren)
                                        <ul class="child-menu">
                                            #foreach ($nav_grandchild in $nav_child.getChildren())
                                                #if ($nav_grandchild.isSelected())
                                                    <li class="selected">
                                                #else
                                                    <li>
                                                #end
                                                <a href="$nav_grandchild.getURL()" class="child-link" $nav_grandchild.getTarget()><span class="sub-navigation-item">$nav_grandchild.getName()</span></a>
                                                </li>
                                            #end
                                        </ul>
                                    #end
                                </li>
                            #end
                        #end
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            #else
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            #end
        #end
```

Help me Obi-wan Kenobi you're my only hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd best loop through the toplevel navigation twice. Once for just building the single-level `<ul>` list. Then, a second time, don't display any top-level `<ul>`, only for the one selected top-level navigation item, display all of its childs, as deeply nested as you'd like.

Pseudocode:

```
<nav id="portal-choice">
<ul>
    #foreach ($nav_item in $nav_items)
        #if ($nav_item.isSelected())
            <li class="selected">
        #else
            <li>
        #end
                <a href="$nav_item.getURL()" $nav_item.getTarget()>$nav_item.icon() $nav_item.getName()</a>
            </li>
    #end
</ul>
</nav>

<nav id="main-nav">
<ul>
    #foreach ($nav_item in $nav_items)
        #if ($nav_item.isSelected())
             #if ($navHasChildren)
                 #foreach ($nav_child in $nav_item.getChildren())
                     <li><!-- display any level of children --></li>
                 #end
             #end
         #end
    #end
</ul>
</nav>
```

Velocity is not really good for recursive application, so the "display any level of children" might contain a bit of duplicated code for all the nested levels you want to display. Or you create a macro - any way, at least this will help you get started. The key is to loop through the navigation twice.

Another alternative is to utilize the "Navigation" Portlet, which you can configure to display all the pages starting at level "1", which would be the child of the current top level page. You'll just embed this portlet in your theme.

Comment: Can you specify "didn't work" a bit more? What was the result and which part of it didn't match the expectation?

Comment: Sorry, made an error when deploying it seems. It works now. Thanks